# how to respond_to a json request with only the 20 recents objects? (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wish to send to the client only the 20 recent Post objects.

How do i that?
I'm new to rails so ill appreciate your advice very much.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
@posts = Post.all(:order => 'created_at desc', :limit => 20)
respond_to do |format|
  format.json  
end
```